# Smallest number starting with N divisble by every non zero digit of N

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We are given a number N and we have to find the smallest number that starts with N and is divisble by every non zero digit of N.How can we do this ?
If N is 13 then answer is 132 .

According to the solution one has to the smallest number between N0.....9 ,N00.....N99 ,N000.....N999 ,N0000.......N2519.
Lcm of (1,2,3...,9)=2520
Can anyone explain this ?

Answer (score 1):

The lcm of all digits  of $N$ is at most (in fact, is a divisor of) the lcm of all non-zero digits, i.e., is at most $2520$. Among the $2520$ consecutive numbers $10^4N+k$, $0\le k <2520$, at least one is a multiple of $2520$ and hence also is "a number starting with $N$ and divisible by every digit of $N$". This gives an upper bound for the smallest such number, and one need only test all smaller numbers starting with $N$ whether any of these is divisible by all digits of $N$. Hence the candidates to tedst are, in ascending order, $N$ (missing from your list!), $10N+k$ for $0\le k<10$, $100N+k$ for $0\le k<100$, $1000N+k$ for $0\le k<1000$, $10000N+k$ for $0\le k<2520$.
Of course we can stop testing as soon as we found a suitable number. For example, $N=13$ leads to $\operatorname{lcm}(1,3)=3$, hence instead of four additional digits up to 2519 we need at must tees one additional digit up to 2 (and only that last test meets our criteria).

Comment: Can you explain the upper bound concept more clearly with an example ?

Comment: @satya How that? In the given example, $N=13$, note that $132$ is obtained by appending at most four digits, and if "2" were four digits it would be less than $2520$. - Actually, I already wrote how to obtain a much smaller upper bound than $10^4N+2519$ for $N=13$

Comment: Why did you skip k=2520 in 10^4N+2519